# While loop continues despite conditional statement becomes false

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using a while loop which is expected to execute as long as the condition remains true, logic in terms of code snippet :

```
while(!(Quiz.nextButton.disabled)){
            
            await utils.click(Quiz.nextButton);
            await utils.click(Quiz.selectOptionButton);
        }
```

Now problem here is that, this loop continues to execute inside even when the conditional statement becomes false. Any help here would be a lot worth.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `Quiz.nextButton.disabled` is not evaluated each time you are performing the `while` loop case validation.
Alternatively `nextButton` element may stay enabled even after clicking on it.

Comment: I too think that conditional statement is not being evaluated each time.

Comment: OK, can you validate if this is the problem here?

Comment: Next button on the last page of quiz is disabled, as verified it through <button> class attribute which displays to be disabled.

Comment: But are you sure `Quiz.nextButton.disabled` will point to the next button on the next pages, not to stay containing reference to the `next page` button on the first page?

Comment: when i use without negation i.e. while(Quiz.nextButton.disabled), it doesn't go inside the loop as the condition is false and works as expected.

Comment: when on first or any other page except last page, nextButton has type="button" and tab index = 0, on last page, this becomes type="button" disabled and tab index = -1